Trial of an alleged rapist. At the end, a single scene explains it all
So the only thing I remember is that it is about a trial for rape , they accuse somebody of raping a girl.
Almost the whole movie occurs in the court.  At the very end, they finally reveal what actually happened, with the scene of the rape.
I am pretty sure most of the movie occurs in the court house, or during the trial, and just untill the end, they show the scene of the rape (although i don't remember if as evidence, or most likely just as a flashback)
EDIT to add more information.
Based on the age I estimate i was when watching it, around 11-13, the movie should be from around mid 90's. I watched it in the movies, so not a "TV movie", but since I watched it in Mexico, the release date here could be different from the original release date in the US.
It is in english (american). The main character was the allegedly raped girl (a woman around her 20's I estimate)... And now I am not sure if it was only one alleged rapist, or several men.
As mentioned, the thing I most remember is that the final scene revealed the truth. Which by the way I don't remember exactly, maybe it was revealed that the girl was lying all the time, or maybe the other way around, the guy(s) were declared innocent, only to reveal that he/they indeed did it. I don't remember much else.

That is not a lot to go on. Do you have any more info? Main stream movie? B-Flick? Enlish or subtitled? Anything?

Is the movie Japanese? Because it sounds like Rashomon.

Rashomon would be a good 40 years off the desired year, slebetman. ;)

Was there a nun? Damn, this movie sounds familiar!

Was the court room flashback shown in a split screen?  The girl's recollection on the left and the boy's on the right showing the different way they were telling the story (what she was wearing, how she spoke etc.)?

Sure sounds like "The Accused." As IMDB plot synopsis explains, the ending features a dramatic flashback to the rape, which shows how the rapists were encouraged by certain spectators -- leading to the spectators being found guilty of criminal solicitation.
At the courthouse, Sarah gives a highly detailed, lengthy account of the night of the rape at The Mill. However, she is unable to ascertain who "applauded or shouted" or to prove that anyone in the bar really saw her struggling... After visiting his friend Bob, Kenneth enters the courthouse. Though aware of the consequences facing Bob, Kenneth recounts what happened that night in a scene structured in flashbacks... In the film's final scenes, Kathryn wins the case, with special thanks to Sarah and Kenneth. All three defendants are found guilty of criminal solicitation.

Thanks. I will try to chech it out and see if it is the one, since I don't remember by just the (few) images available in IMDB.

Very little of The Accused take place in the courtroom.

Based on your "one scene explains it all" I assume it is some sort of movie with a twist ending. 
For some reason, The Life of David Gale comes to my mind, although it is from 2003 and is with Kevin Spacey(who is pretty well known, but still you haven't specified his name). The description doesn't mention any rape, but there actually is one in the movie. 
I don't know how many details I should provide in order to not spoil it for you, since you have apparently forgotten all the details.

Thanks, but definitely is not that one.

I'm guessing this isn't The Accused either, right?

The Accused synopsis sounds similar. But the release date (1988) makes it unlikely, since I was 5 then, i really doubt I saw a film like that at such age (specially on the movies) I was young, but not that much, so it is more likely to be a mid 90's movie...

OK. But FWIW, I think the scene showing the actual crime was near the end of The Accused.
